# Compile PHP with GD for iPhone OS 4.1

Tags: php, iphone, ios4, compilation, gd

### The Goal:

have a working version of PHP with the GD library working on an iPod Touch 4th Gen.

### The Status:

PHP is working on the iPod (lighttpd + PHP 5.2.8 + sqlite3) without GD.

When trying to compile PHP on the iPod I get this error: http://pastebin.com/kUmgq70G

### The Proposed Solution:

Can anyone point me in the direction of how to **compile PHP with GD and then package it up nicely as a .deb file** for everyone else to use?

---

The best situation I believe is to compile the latest version of PHP with the GD library included and enabled.  Second best would be to settle for compiling GD as a module and then installing that into the currently working PHP that is available from Cydia.  However to compile GD you would have to do this with the SAME source that was used to create the php_5.2.8-3_iphoneos-arm.deb available from Cydia - I think it would be easier and safer for everyone in the future to just compile a fresh PHP with GD already enabled and then pack it up as a .deb

---

Here is what I have from phpinfo of the currently installed version of PHP:
System:

```
Darwin iPod-Touch 10.3.1 Darwin Kernel Version 10.3.1: Wed Aug 4 22:35:51 PDT 2010; root:xnu-1504.55.33~10/RELEASE_ARM_S5L8930X iPod4,1
```

Build Date:

```
Jan 25 2009 02:55:42
```

Configure Command:

```
'./configure' '--build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu' '--host=arm-apple-darwin9' '--enable-static=no' '--enable-shared=yes' '--prefix=/usr' '--localstatedir=/var/cache/php' '--with-iconv=/usr/arm-apple-darwin9/usr' '--with-curl=/home/dat/apl/tel/dest/iphoneos-arm/curl/usr' '--enable-fastcgi'
```

---

Here is the package information from Cydia's repo:

```
Package: php
Version: 5.2.8-3
Architecture: iphoneos-arm
Maintainer: Jay Freeman (saurik) <saurik@saurik.com>
Installed-Size: 14492
Depends: curl, libxml2
Filename: debs/php_5.2.8-3_iphoneos-arm.deb
Size: 4626280
MD5sum: dbb30ea608945a5d45de02df74df71b0
Section: Development
Priority: optional
Description: overly popular HTML templating language
Name: PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor
Tag: purpose::console, role::developer
```

---

P.S.  I am not the only person working on this, as during my searching I found several other posts with people who need this too.  Once I have this completed I will host the file somewhere so that everyone can enjoy.

Comment: You need a cross-compiler setup for that, `export CC=/usr/local/arm/3.4.1/bin/arm-linux-gcc`. And it gets more involving since you also need to cross compile GD first. No good links, sorry.

Comment: I have looked all over the internet for what's called a toolchain - apparently this is the gadget that is responsible for the "./configure" and "make" commands... But I was not able to find anything that looked reliable to use for the iOS4.1

Comment: currently I am working on getting Xcode with the apple SDK - maybe I can just build it right within this application.  If that is the case than later I will find a way to package it up and the goal will be complete.  But I have to go upgrade my operating system from 10.5 to 10.6 :( first... so once I've done that I will update this page.

Comment: Okay, so here's a small update - I was up until 6:something a.m. last night compiling from the iPod its self... the only problem is my environment is hacked together from 2.0 header files and 4.1 header/libs from the SDK - and that plus other things maybe be making an unstable compiling environment.  I have all of PHP's dependencies compiled but PHP its self is being a bit of a bitch to compile.  I keep running into different problems, but going backwards in version seamed to help the first one.  I'm not sure why.  My C++ college days was more than 9 years ago :P

Comment: so, i've gotten to the point where I have a toolchain suposedly working on my iPod 4th Gen - but I still can't get PHP to compile all the way, it keeps bucking out on some errors.  I found ONE patch suggestion submitted to PHP which looks like it solves the problem, but I don't know how to apply it manually - stuck there...

Comment: or I could just compile GD its self and install just that one section into PHP and enable it as a module, except when i use the command phpize the configure file only has ONE line in it and is useless...  I think my automake/autoconfiguration is broken there - but then again I'm not sure.  I can get the GD files compiled as far as .lo files - but because the "make" command craps out half way through compiling PHP I can't ever get them into the ever needed .so files which I could just copy into PHP and enable GD as a module.  So, that's my current stuck place :(

Comment: if anyone is interested in helping remove any one of the roadblocks I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Here is what happens when I try and compile - if I can get past this, then I can make a tutorial on how to accomplish this task: http://pastebin.com/kUmgq70G

Comment: Whoever voted for close with "too localised"... What?!?

Comment: Kent: this is because if you go into irc.freenode #iphonedev and work on any project outside of the Apple SDK they will band you.  Don't trust me?  Go there and say the word "Cydia" and watch what happens... its like walking into a church during mass and screaming the "eff" word.

Comment: here is some of my progress today logged in these pastebins.  not like this will help anyone, but shows I'm still working on this everyone. http://pastebin.com/kUmgq70G
http://pastebin.com/ym2QjKJL
http://pastebin.com/PCfq6wv3
http://pastebin.com/Ywq3x67s
http://pastebin.com/LcuiiU1z
http://pastebin.com/A6GnLTMz
http://pastebin.com/HSKPazF7
http://pastebin.com/gy45NaZh
http://pastebin.com/yMHp3TyV
http://pastebin.com/sBSRv3v3
http://pastebin.com/Z38PGTwk
http://pastebin.com/7D1xgAfi

Comment: @Jeremy : its stil very "WTF" for stackoverflow. Not to mention, it is a very bad close resolution, you can't just mark something for closure simply because "I don't like it" .....

Comment: big thanks for your efforts. i'd also like to have php with gd on my idevice (iphone 2g, 3.1.2).

Comment: Yep, really hard to find any solution. Maybe the packager could make a second package which includes gd compiled in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This never happened.  Saurik never responded to me either.  So I dropped this project.

Answer (score 1):

From your output it seems that php compiles fine, but fails to link to the resolv library.

If you need a workaround for getting PHP 5.2, you will need to manually add -lresolv to the linker flags.

This seems to be a bug in PHP 5.2 compiled with apple's tools (http://bugs.php.net/49332) which is fixed in PHP 5.3, so you might try 5.3 one unless you really need 5.2 for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't tried myself, but the Saurik repository should help :

> http://svn.telesphoreo.org/trunk/

And especially this one might interest you :

> http://svn.telesphoreo.org/trunk/data/php/

Cydia packages comes from that, thanks Saurik for his huge work of course!